# Loading BitMap Images - Xamarin.Andoird

Tags: c#, android, bitmap

I am performing a bitmap resize in my application. I have a folder called Bitmap Images which has the function initiating the bitmap resize. But in my adapter(this line of code), `hold.Img.SetImageBitmap(BitmapImages.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),news[position].Image,100,100));`, The first parameter `getResource` is raised as an error. What is missing?

```
public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter

    {
        private JavaList<News> news;



        public MyAdapter(JavaList<News> news)
        {
            this.news = news;

        }

        //binding data to views
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            MyHolder hold = holder as MyHolder;
            hold.Comment.Text = news[position].Comment;
            //hold.Img.SetImageResource(news[position].Image);
            hold.Img.SetImageBitmap(BitmapImages.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),news[position].Image,100,100));


        }
```

Comment: Post your error

Comment: @Yupi, i haven't run the app yet since the resource  is already being underlined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not passing the `Context`. To access `getResources()` you have to pass `Context`. So modify your adapter class.

```
public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter

{
    private JavaList<News> news;
    private Context context;



    public MyAdapter(JavaList<News> news, Context context)
    {
        this.news = news;
        this.context = context;
    }

   ......
 //Then in your OnBindViewHolder you can call getResources
  .....
   hold.Img.SetImageBitmap(BitmapImages.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(),news[position].Image,100,100));
 }
```

Comment: Also after this you will have to provide context where you are creating instance of `MyAdapter` class as Context is provided in constructor of class.